# `systemctl status` information on `Condition...` failures disappears, how is this ever useful?

Tags: systemd

I created a test unit with a failing Condition, and started it.  `systemctl status` can show information about the Condition failure... but *only* if I contrive to have my test service in a failed state.

```
# systemctl status test.service -n0
● test.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-10 17:01:35 BST; 16s ago
Condition: start condition failed at Tue 2018-07-10 17:01:51 BST; 1s ago
           └─ ConditionKernelCommandLine=not-an-option was not met
 Main PID: 4378 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The failed state was a way to stop the unit being garbage-collected and forgotten.  But otherwise, the unit is forgotten and you can't see the Condition information.  And Condition failures aren't logged to the journal either - only the failure state I contrived earlier.

```
# systemctl reset-failed test.service
# systemctl status test.service
● test.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 10 17:01:35 fedora28-vm systemd[1]: Starting test.service...
Jul 10 17:01:35 fedora28-vm systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 10 17:01:35 fedora28-vm systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 10 17:01:35 fedora28-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start test.service.
```

So how are you supposed to use this `systemctl` feature?  Normally, when you start your unit, the failing Condition will be tested first, and the start process will be skipped.  So there is no chance for it to enter a failed state.

Tested on systemd version v239-120-g0fad72fae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works OK once you enable your unit to be started as part of the boot process.  Units are prevented from being garbage collected, if they are depended on by an active unit such as `multi-user.target`.

I added these lines to the unit

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then I was able to use it as I wanted:

```
# systemctl enable test.service
# systemctl start test.service
# systemctl status test.service -n0

● test.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Tue 2018-07-10 17:18:21 BST; 3s ago
           └─ ConditionKernelCommandLine=not-an-option was not met
```